# Android WebView and WebSockets / Paho.MQTT

Tags: javascript, android, websocket, android-webview, java-websocket

all similiar questions are already a few years ago so I might ask again:

I made a website which includes the Paho.MQTT javascript client (mqttws31.js).
It works fine on all browsers (also in Chrome on Android).

Here's my code:

```
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("ws://iot.eclipse.org/ws", "myClientId" + new Date().getTime());
```

This part doesn't work in a native android app within a `WebView`.

**Are WebSockets not supported in general or is it a Paho.MQTT problem? Is there a fast and easy work-around?**
Some parts of my website are using SignalR - which works fine in a WebView...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

figured it out....

`var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("ws://iot.eclipse.org/ws", "myClientId");`

did not work because local storage is disabled by default.

Enabling it in my Android WebView solved the issue.
`_mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Comment: I'm having this same issue in 2023 - mqtt with paho js web client works fine on pc, but android chrome and apple the client.send() never sends anything